# Select two HTML elements at the same time in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I have a HTML file which looks about like this:

```
<div class="mon_title">[CURRENT DATE]</div>
<table class="mon_list" >[contents of the table]</table>
[OHER CODE]
<div class="mon_title">[ANOTHER DATE]</div>
<table class="mon_list" >[contents of another table]</table>
[repeats a few times over]
```

My end-goal is to extract the tables and somehow add the corresponding date to each.

Using this code I successfully extracted only the tables:

```
tables = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "mon_list"})
```

My question is how I can extract both the date and the table and somehow add the corresponding date to each table.

Comment: *add the corresponding date to each table* - Could you elaborate this ? Do you wish to insert the date as a row inside the table ?

Comment: thats why I said somehow. It really does not matter to me if the result just prints the date over each table still in html or adds it to the table itself.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`find_all` support custom function, [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all).

Here an example of usage

```
html = """<div class="mon_title">[CURRENT DATE]</div>
<table class="mon_list" >[contents of the table]</table>
<div class="mon_title">[ANOTHER DATE]</div>
<table class="mon_list" >[contents of another table]</table><span>hhhh</span>"""

import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

def finder(tag1, tag2):
    def _wrapper(tag):
        if tag.name == tag1 or tag.name == tag2:
            return True   
    return _wrapper

tags = soup.find_all(finder('table', 'div'))

print([tag.text if tag.name == 'div' else tag for tag in soup.find_all(finder('table', 'div'))])
```

Output

```
['[CURRENT DATE]', <table class="mon_list">[contents of the table]</table>, '[ANOTHER DATE]', <table class="mon_list">[contents of another table]</table>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

- Select the `<table>` with the class name as `mon_list` using `find_all()`
- For each table selected above, since the date `<div>` is present before the `<table>` element, you can select it using the `.findPreviousSibling()` method.

  ```
  .findPreviousSibling('div', class_='mon_title')
  ```

Here is the complete code that will print the date first and then the table data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """
<div class="mon_title">[CURRENT DATE]</div>
<table class="mon_list" >[contents of the table]</table>
[OHER CODE]
<div class="mon_title">[ANOTHER DATE]</div>
<table class="mon_list" >[contents of another table]</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
tabs = soup.find_all('table', class_='mon_list')
for tab in tabs:
    date_div = tab.findPreviousSibling('div', class_='mon_title')
    print(f"Date: {date_div.text.strip()}\nTable Data: {tab.text.strip()}\n")
```

```
Date: [CURRENT DATE]
Table Data: [contents of the table]

Date: [ANOTHER DATE]
Table Data: [contents of another table]
```